# Avoiding multiplying zeros in matrix solver

Tags: vba

Is there a way to avoid multiplying zeros as part of an inner a loop? As a laughable test I tried a conditional to stop the multiplication if it encounters a zero, and of course this is slower then just doing the multiplication. My preference is to leave the LU matrix intact, rather than rearrange to make zeros disappear (sparse). In this instance language is VBA prior to conversion to VB.net.

```
    For k = 1 To i - 1
        If LU(j, k) <> 0 and LU(k, i) <> 0 Then temp = temp - LU(j, k) * LU(k, i) 
    Next k
```

Thanks.

Comment: what do you propose as the 'avoid' method - replace 0 with another number? skip the calculation? ignore the result?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to avoid multiplying by zeroes if you want to preserve the matrix structure.

Furthermore, sparse matrices are not supported in VBA so you would have to code your own class for sparse matrices : the idea is that instead of storing the entire matrix, you just store index/value pairs.

A sparse matrix class would include methods to :

- create a matrix with given values in index/value form.
- create a sparse matrix from given values in array form.
- multiply two sparse matrices (including the special case sparse matrix times sparse vector)

Answer (score 0):

Macroman, I mean to skip the calculation if zeros encountered to speed up solution. Thanks.

Titus, already wrote a fully pivoted LUD solver for VBA which can (slowly) solve sparse matrices. I just wanted to see if it was feasible to convert solver to Sparse techniques. Memory is not an issue, hence preference to avoid index/value storage technique, so I just wanted see if there was a fast way to make solver skip zeros to speed it up. Thanks.